# changes to model in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

All,

I need clarification on how model changes need to tracked in ruby on rails. I started off by creating a model with say two fields, name and email. Here is what i have done

1. Created a model by running

"rails generate model user first_name:string last_name:string"

This created a model file

1. I then added some validations to the files created in user
2. Used the annotation gem to annotate the class
3. used "bundle exec rake db:migrate" to move my model to database which created the tables

I now want to add a couple more fields to the model. What steps do i need to follow?

1. Do i add columns to the database and run some command so that the model(class) is in sync with the db?
2. Do i delete and recreate the whole model with the new fields?

what is the recommended approach
Venu

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a migration to update the existing table, you can do the entire process from the command line

Assuming you've done

```
rails generate model user first_name:string last_name:string
```

previously you would add fields like so;

```
rails generate migration AddFieldsToModel new_field:string another_field:string....
```

Rails does magic on the 'AddFieldsToModel' and works out the table name from the  value  for you.

Once you've created the migration you can look at it in db/migrations and then if you're happy with it just run

```
rake db:migrate
```

this will update your database to add the new fields to it. You don't need to do anything to the actual model.rb file - but you will need to re run the annotate task to have it reannotated to the model.rb file.

Comment: Is it a true statement that rails will "fill in" this model with all the fields from the database? and the names of the fields will be the same as the column names? Are these going to be object level variables?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of rails your are using .. but int rails 3.x it can be done as

```
rails generate migration add_fields_user
```

this creates  a file in db/migrate/[timestamp]/add_fields_user.rb

now you can write in the file and run rake db:migrate

```
add_column :users , :city, :string
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is run a migration by typing. rails generate migration description_of_migration. This will create an empty migration which you can define what you want to add to your model. In your case it may be something like this:

```
class DescriptionOfMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

self.up 
 add_column :users, :email, :string  
end

self.down
 remove_column :users, :email
end

end
```

This makes it so you can migrate both ways on the model.